# Browserify - add html5shiv to bundle.js

Tags: browserify, html5shiv

I am trying to use Browserify - however bundling 'html5shiv.js' doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Node_Sports_Lineup",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js",
    "test": "mocha tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "ejs": "*",
    "express": "^3.17.5",
    "express-generator": "^4.9.0",
    "express-session": "*",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoskin": "*",
    "monk": "*",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "mocha": "*",
    "request": "*",
    "busboy": "*",
    "busboy-body-parser": "*",
    "mongoose-session": "*",
    "mongoose-validate": "*",
    "passport-linkedin": "*",
    "util": "*",
    "nodemailer": "*",
    "crypto": "*",
    "uniq": "*",
    "jquery":"*",
    "underscore":"*",
    "backbone":"*",
    "bootstrap":"*",
    "html5shiv":"*",
    "respond":"*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-open": "^0.2.3",
    "grunt-typescript": "^0.4.4",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

and in my other file, I have it required just like everything else

//browserDependencies.js

```
var uniq = require('uniq');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var underscore = require('underscore');
var backbone = require('backbone');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var html5shiv = require('html5shiv');
var respond = require('respond');
```

can html5shiv be used like the others in this manner?

Comment: It's designed to be used with bower, not npm, and to exposed on the global scope.  These issues can be solved with: https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify and https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim

Comment: @generalhenry, by "it" you are referring to "html5shiv", when I first read your comment a few days ago I thought it referred to browserify as a whole, pronouns man!